# Use Hashmap in macro as TokenTree

Tags: rust, hashmap, macros

I'm facing a really strange case which seems to be very easy to resolve but whatever I try to do I cannot get a proper solution.

I'm using external library which provides me a macro that takes a `tt` (TokenTree) as an argument. Syntax of usage looks something like this:

```rust
some_macro!(
    "some name"  => "some value",
    "other name" => "other value"
);
```

Logic of my solution gives me a `Hashmap` of keys and values that I want to map to that TokenTree. Is it possible?

```rust
some_macro!(my_hashmap);
```

Of course I don't know all the keys at compile time.

There's one catch: I have to use a stable version of Rust.

Comment: No, macros are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @kmdreko Alright, so this answer probably ends my history with this solution. 
Thanks mate. (When i reach 15 reputation I will give u a point ;d)

Comment: Can you link to the library? It might be possible that the macro operates on expressions, like `vec!` does,  but I can't tell if I don't know what macro it is.

Comment: https://github.com/metrics-rs/metrics
I would like to write some kind of wrapper for `counter!` macro using builder and use Hashmap as a cointeiner for labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with this library, however, what you want does seem to be possible. Looking at the documentation, it appears you can use owned strings and slices of key-value pairs instead of string literals. If you are consuming a `HashMap` and loading the contents into the macro it might look something like this:

```rust
fn hash_map_to_counter(map:HashMap<String,String>){
  let labels:Vec<_> = map.drain().collect();
  counter!("some name", 12, &labels);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. 
It's not working at v0.0.12 but i forgot to mention that. 
Your solution will work with the newest version so now all i can do is a workaround without hashmap and wait for Actix be stable with tokio 1.0.

Thanks, i'll give point someday when 15 reputation will occur on my account. ;)

Comment: @Xavrax Sorry to hear about the version issue, I hate it when that happens. Also, I get a 15 rep bonus just for getting my answer accepted- no need to award it manually.

Comment: @Alden4 Nice to hear. 
I found solution for this library and version. You have to get `metrics_core` stuff and mimic `counter!. :) But still I thnk that it's not the best solution.